# Grails load CSS from custom URL

Tags: html, css, grails

Using Grails version 2.4.4. and trying to load CSS resource from URL

1. `http://myAppName.com:7777/myApp/assets/style.css`
2. `/myApp/assets/style.css`

I've set in `style.css`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?t0751g');
  src:  url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?t0751g#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?t0751g') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?t0751g') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?t0751g#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Beside this, I added few other options for proper icon load.

Assets structure:

`/assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf` (and all other icomoon files are here)

```
/assets/stylesheets/style.css
```

when I use 2. url it loads my custom icons normally but when I set the 1. url in `<style>` as shown above, icon loading fails.

Both url-s should point to the same file and I don't understand why this is not working. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong ?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that fonts does not support cross-origin domain, and I used icomoon icons as font to import it from another domain. On the other hand, i found out you can use Fontello which generates embedded JS and automatically fixes this issues, so it is generally better to use.